# Simple 'in-file' completion with XCode

Tags: xcode, vim, ctrlp

XCode has really good completion when it comes to library functions.
But is there any way to accomplish simple 'in-file' completion like sublime or vim (with ctrl-p) does?

For example I define a variable named `myCustomSuperVariable`.
Now when I enter `myCu`, there should be a possibility to complete it, right?